# In Pandas, does .where(cond, other) compute _other_ regardless of _cond_?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with values which may or may not be normalized.

```
+---+------------+
| x | normalized |
+---+------------+
| 1 | True       |
+---+------------+
| 2 | True       |
+---+------------+
| 3 | False      |
+---+------------+
| 4 | True       |
+---+------------+
| 5 | False      |
+---+------------+
```

My current way of normalizing all `x` is

```
df.x = df.x.where(df.normalized, normalize)
```

`normalize` is a function and may take significant amounts of time, so i was wondering if `normalize` gets called on every value of `x` whether or not `normalized` is True. I suspect yes based on `pandas/core/generic.py`.

If it is, is a better way to `apply(lambda ...)` or use `for row in df.iterrows(): ...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faster is use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) because pandas is built in numpy arrays:

```
normalize = 10
df.x = np.where(df.normalized.values, df.x.values, normalize)
print (df)
    x  normalized
0   1        True
1   2        True
2  10       False
3   4        True
4  10       False
```

Yes, so it's better to use this - filtering both sides by boolean mask column:

```
def normalize(x):
    return x + 10

df.loc[df.normalized, 'x'] = df.loc[df.normalized, 'x'].apply(normalize)
print (df)
    x  normalized
0  11        True
1  12        True
2   3       False
3  14        True
4   5       False
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more *why* it's better? To me, the logic is identical, i.e. `normalize` is pre-computed for the entire series in *both* cases, so there is no complexity advantage. Moreover, `pd.Series.where` is somewhat cleaner as you don't have to say "do nothing in case X".

Comment: @jpp - Faster is better word.

Comment: i think i wasn't clear that `normalize` is a function, which means you have to write `df.x = np.where(df.normalized.values, df.x.values, df.x.apply(normalize))`... is that really faster?

Comment: if you could edit the answer to say "Yes, so it's better to use this...", i'll accept, thanks!

Comment: @iamanigeeit - Sorry, my english is no nice, if think something else be free help me create better sentence. Thanks.

Comment: Related: [Pandas mask / where methods versus NumPy np.where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51982417/pandas-mask-where-methods-versus-numpy-np-where)